# Adding additional entries to image's "Details" tab in the gallery

Tags: android, image, image-gallery

In the Gallery, if you click on an image, the three points and then on Details (dont now if it is the same on all phones), you can see Additional Infos of the Image (e.g. File Size, Resolution, Date Taken), as you can see

[image]

Now, if I code a App that can take a photo, is there any way to add custom entries to this Window? For example a custom text, the cardinal direction in which the phone pointed, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way to add custom entries to this Window?

Not in general.

There are ~2 billion Android devices. These are spread across ~10,000 device models. Those device models will ship with dozens, if not hundreds, of pre-installed "gallery" apps. There are many more such apps available for download from the Play Store and other app distribution channels.

Out of those hundreds to thousands of "gallery" apps, few will have the ability to display any sort of image properties in a screen like you show. And, those that do, may only show a few specific ones. For example, a JPEG can have [several dozen different EXIF tags](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface.html), and your screenshot is showing exactly 0 of them.

That even assumes that the image file type *support* the concept of metadata, the way that JPEG images do with EXIF tags. For example, I'm not sure that PNG files have that capability.

So, *if* the image type supports metadata (e.g., JPEG) and *if* the data that you want to put in the image fits that metadata structure (e.g., matching EXIF tag), you can put your metadata into the image (e.g., using [`ExifInterface` from the support library](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/media/ExifInterface.html)). Whether any other app will *do* anything with that metadata is up to the developers of the other app.